# Can you automate the writing of test cases in selenium using a logger?

Tags: javascript, logging, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Is it feasible to automate the writing of test cases by using the info logs with Selenium Webdriver. I am developing a testing framework in protractor using the page object design and would like to have it write out the test steps in the logs (or in a plain text file) to make a human readable copy of the test case if needed.

An example of how I was thinking of structuring it was putting the logger in my methods.

```
var logger = require('/.log')

login = function(username, password){
     usernameTextField.sendKeys(username);
     passwordTextField.sendKeys(password);
     loginButton.click();
     logger.log('info', 'Log in to the website')
};
```

If anyone has any experience using something like this and found it hard to maintain I would like to know what types of problems were encountered.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create a text file with the test steps that protractor exeuctes? If yes, then jasmine already has something called specs, where you can write a test step as description to it. There are reporters that produce results in the form of html or console. If not, please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @GirishSortur  Yes I would like to create a text file. What i want specifically is for each action to be documented like they would be in a normal manual test case. One thing I want to do is avoid having to write out the test steps each time. I want to embed  test step in the function so I only need to write it once.

Comment: Jasmine specs have the test steps written as their description, which you can always access. If you want to write a step for an external function, then yes you can add your own logger that creates a text file and adds steps into it every time the function executes. Thanks

Comment: If it's a good page object design, it will be almost human readable anyway... if yours isn't close enough, you could rename your function like `loginWithUsernameAndPassword({username: foo, password: bar})` and write the javascript function accordingly. Or like `clickTheLoginButton() = function() { loginButton.click() }`